# How to deploy a multi tenant app on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, multi-tenant

I'm using the Apartment gem in ruby on rails to work with multitenancy and in local host works fantastic, but I did deploy to heroku and I get redirect to the main page of heroku

[image]

I have my own domain but when I visit my domain just says:

**This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.**

so I dont know what to do, I need to use amazon ? you know some configuration guys ?

Regards ! and thanks for your time !

Comment: This? http://lifesforlearning.com/heroku-with-godaddy/

Comment: @DavidAldridge I already did all of that is not problem of godaddy configuration I think is heroku because doesnt support multitenancy but I'm not sure so thats why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make work the multi-tenant on heroku so I did it in aws ec2 and works very well !